# httpd with django3 with python3.6 on Centos7

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, linux, apache

we are trying to run django3 (python3.6 on Centos7) with httpd.

i get following error when i run it by HTTPD.

````
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575618 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575665 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]   File "/srv/django/django/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575670 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]     application=get_wsgi_application()
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575678 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575682 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575690 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575694 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575701 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575706 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]     self._setup(name)
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575713 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575717 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575724 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575729 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575736 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575740 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575747 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575755 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575762 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Tue Jan 12 06:52:04.575780 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 16778] [remote 100.10.100.10:53489] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.settings'```
````

my django.conf file in /etc/httpd/conf.d is as follows:

```
Alias /static /srv/static
<Directory /srv/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /srv/django/django>
   <Files wsgi.py>
       Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess django python-path=/srv/django:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup django
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/django/django/wsgi.py
```

and my wsgi.py as as follows:

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.chdir('/srv/django/')
sys.path.append('/srv/django/')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django.settings')
application=get_wsgi_application()
```

we installed following packages

```
python3-devel.x86_64 
rh-python36-mod_wsgi.x86_64
yum install httpd-devel
```

django project as such is working fine

```
100.10.100.10 (/srv/django/)-1003> python3 manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 12, 2021 - 05:22:31
Django version 3.1.5, using settings 'django.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar on how well Apache Httpd works with WSGI, but if you're starting Django separately and you simply want to a reverse proxy up an running quickly you could do the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ProxyRequests off
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    # SSLProxyEngine on
    # ProxyPreserveHost On

    ServerName www.yoursite.net

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel error

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://www.yourwebsite.net/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

In terms of the error, it looks like wsgi.py can't find `django.settings` meaning the `django` directory and `settings` module aren't in the current path.